# Laravel does not find css file : GET http://localhost:8000/cssFile net::ERR_ABORTED

Tags: php, css, laravel, ubuntu

My laravel project does not find any of the css files of any of the pages. It shows up with the error,

```
GET http://localhost:8000/dashboard.css net::ERR_ABORTED
```

Did not find too many of the similar questions but tried the some solutions that I have found but obviously those did not help, otherwise I would not be asking again.

I`m using a Ubuntu PC.

Here are everything that I have tried.

1. Checked file permissions, all the files have all `read, write and execution` privileges.
2. Tried restarting the localhost many times.
3. Tried using the `asset()` function, `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{asset('dashboard.css')}}">`
4. Tried using absolute path though I have the `css` files in the same directory as the `blade.php` files.

None of the above mentioned ways fixed it. Some clue would help me a lot. Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The CSS files need to be in the public folder, or a subfolder of public, not the view folder where the blade php files are.  public is where you want to put any javascript files, css files, images, or whatever, and the root of the public folder becomes the root of your website when it's running.

Comment: Thanks for you response. I have put it in the /public/css folder. I changed it to 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/home/toorja/Desktop/Blog/public/css/dashboard.css"> 
..
Still did not work.

Comment: Public is the web root, not part of your path. Try just href=“css/dashboard.css” (use the proper kind of quotation marks of course)

Comment: just use `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{asset('css/dashboard.css')}}">`

Comment: @RatnadeepChakraborty u may accept the answer if it works